# Как считывать комбинацию клавиш (W+D) (UP+RIGHT)

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Собственно, сами клавиши с определением направления через Enum (`Direction.UP`, `Direction.RIGHT`), `playerDirection` - для проверки направления в `switch`. При нажатии на стрелку вверх - прыжок, направо - движение направо.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        playerDirection = Direction.UP;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D || key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        playerDirection = Direction.RIGHT;
    }
}
```

Switch..case выглядит примерно так:

```
switch(playerDirection){
    case UP:
        jump();
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        mapX -= speed;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Проблема в том, что никак не могу реализовать прыжок вправо (он выполняет действие только последней нажатой клавиши). Может можно как-то считывать комбинацию клавиш? Или есть какие-то другие способы

Comment: Используйте не "событие -> действие", а "событие -> состояние -> действие". То есть сохраняйте состояние кнопок (нажата/ненажата) и потом смотря по тому какие кнопки нажаты - выбирайте действие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и написали, нужно следить за состоянием. При нажатии клавиши, добавлять ее в список, при отпускании - удалять. В нужный момент проверять какие клавиши зажаты.

```
private List<Integer> keyCodes = ew ArrayList<>();
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    keyCodes.add(key);

    if(isPressed(List.of(KeyEvent.VK_W,KeyEvent.VK_UP))){
        // do on W and UP pressed
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    keyCodes.remove(key);
}

public boolean isPressed(List<Integer> keys){
    return keyCodes.containsAll(keys);
}
```

Примерно так это выглядит.